# Google Now says it's not available in my country

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, rooting, google-now, miui, localization

On my Xiaomi M2A, Google Now complains that it's not available in my country. 
I know for a fact that Google Now *is* available in the Netherlands, because it works fine on my Galaxy Note 10.1 tablet.

So apparently, Google Now thinks it's in some other country (possibly China, since that's where I ordered this phone). But the phone has been configured to use the Dutch settings everywhere I could find. (Silly enough, the message is actually in Dutch).

So where does Google Now get the idea that it's somewhere else? And (more importantly), how do I tell it that it is, in fact, in the Netherlands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'll be damned.

It seems that Google Now refuses to run on a rooted device, but it just doesn't say so.

The vendor had installed an app to enable rooting of the device. I'd played around with it, but root access was disabled after the first upgrade of MiUI. I didn't really miss root access, to be honest, so it let it be. Ziggo (my cable TV provider)'s TV-watching app did refuse to let me watch TV, though, because it claimed that I wasn't using "an original operating system".

Recently, I tried uninstalling the (Chinese) root manager app -- I can't read Chinese anyway. Uninstalling turned out to be impossible, but after clicking around a bit, and disabling most things I saw, suddenly Google Now became available! And Ziggo suddenly allowed me to watch TV on my device!

So apparently, Google Now refuses to run on a rooted device! Ziggo's TV-watching app was more honest: at least it *told* me it refused to operate on a rooted device..

Answer (score 1):

Since Google Now isn't actually available in my country, I did some looking around, and found this "hack" in a blog :
http://thenepalidroidguy.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-enable-google-now_6.html
In case that the link dies, these are the steps described there :

> Make sure you have an active internet connection and follow all the
>   steps below carefully.
>
> Step 1: Turn on Airplane mode in your device. Now turn on Wifi and
>   connect it to your Wifi network.
>
> Step 2: Go to Settings>Location  & switch to "Device only" mode
>
> Step 3: Install this app from Playstore (Fake gps - fake location)
>   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fakegps.mock
>
> Step 4: Open the app and set the location to "Miami" (I chose Miami
>   but you can select any other places in the USA which would get
>   guaranteed Google Now support). It might ask you to enable mock
>   location first, do that from the developer options in the settings.
>   Now go back to the Fake gps app and set the location to Miami by
>   searching Miami and hitting Play icon on the bottom.
>
> Step 5: Go to Settings and tap in "Google" under Accounts. Then select
>   "Search". Go to Accounts & privacy> Google Account and sign out.
>
> Step 6: Go to Settings>Apps>All and look for Google Play Services. Tap
>   on it and Disable it. It may ask you to uninstall updates and restore
>   to factory version, do it. You might have to deactivate Google Play
>   Services form the Device Administrator first.
>
> Step 7: Go to Settings and tap in "Google" under Accounts. Then select
>   "Search". Go to Accounts & privacy> Google Account and sign in to your
>   Google account.
>
> Step 8: Google Now setup screen should come up. Select I'm in. (It's
>   obvious).
>
> Step 9: Now it may prompt you to Re-enable Google Play Services, do it
>   and an update might be available for Google Play Services, update it
>   from Playstore. Then Turn off Airplane Mode. Uninstall Fake gps app
>   and choose the location service mode of your choice under
>   Settings>Location.
>
> Step 10: You did it. Enjoy Google Now!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).